# Revert the DataGridViewCell to the value before it was changed by the user

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` like this:

[image: pic]

The `Quantidade` column can be changed by the user and the others are read only. I came up with this code that if the user changes the value of `Quantidade` manually on the `DataGridView` it checks the database to see if it has enough in stock. So if the value inputted by the user is less than the total in stock it changes normally but my question is if the user inputs a value bigger than the value in stock I want the `DataGridViewCell` to return to the value before it has been changed by the user.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Here is the code of the event:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
   'this part is to check the total of the product in the db
    Dim Produtoid As String = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
    Dim tabelaqndDisponivel As DataTable = CAD.GetData("SELECT quantidadeExistenteProduto FROM Produto where idProduto = " & Produtoid)
    'qntDisponivel is a integer that holds the total quantity of the product in the db
    Dim qntDisponivel As Integer = tabelaqndDisponivel.Rows(0).Item(0)

    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value <= qntDisponivel Then
        'inserts normally
    Else
        'now here the value on cell "quantidade" should revert
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that This `DataGridView` is pretty simple. It takes the value from the `ComboBox` `Produto` and text from the `TextBox` `Quantidade`

Comment: well i think i know what to do. so if the cell validating saves the "value before user change" i could save it in a variable and then in the CellValueChanged on the else i can revert the cell value to that variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative that I often use is to save it to the `.Tag`, every object has a `.Tag` and it saves declaring a variable globally if you want to use it throughout the code.

Whilst not necessarily shorter code it does prove very useful at times and overall is tidier in my opinion as you don't have to declare a variable (you can save it to the cell or row `.Tag` but that is even longer code).

Usage in your application:

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
    DataGridView1.Tag = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value
End Sub
```

Retrieval:

```
Else
    'now here the value on cell "quantidade" reverts to the value before being changed  
    DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView1.Tag
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is to provide some help on a few issues with your code. Since we have already discussed your question at hand and a fix has been implemented I think it would be worthwhile addressing these issues.

Turn [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx):

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.

First `DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value` is type `Object` and so to resolve this we need to append `.ToString()` to it like so:

```
Dim Produtoid As String = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
```

Second `tabelaqndDisponivel.Rows(0).Item(0)` and `DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value` are too type `Object`. With these I would handle using [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx). You can then also check the `Integer` values correctly:

```
Dim qntDisponivel As Integer = 0
Dim qnt As Integer = 0 'You can give this a more meaningful name
If Integer.TryParse(tabelaqndDisponivel.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString(), qntDisponivel) AndAlso
   Integer.TryParse(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value.ToString(), qnt) Then

    If qnt <= qntDisponivel Then
        'inserts normally
    Else
        'now here the value on cell "quantidade" reverts to the value before being changed  
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = valorqnt
    End If

Else
    'Haven't been able to check so revert
    DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = valorqnt

End If
```

Thirdly `DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value` inside your `CellValidating` method is again type `Object`. Change using `Integer.TryParse`:

```
Integer.TryParse(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value.ToString(), valorqnt)
```

Lastly your SQL statement is open to **SQL injection**. You would need to look into SQL parameters. It's quite difficult to provide much help in this area as I can't see what `GetData` does and it would be outside the scope of this question but it is definitely worth a mention.

Answer (score 1):

So what I did here was create a variable `Private valorqnt As Integer` and on the event `CellValidating` I saved the value (before being changed by the user) into it.

Code:

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
    valorqnt = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value
End Sub
```

This way I have the value of the cell before being changed. Now on the `CellValueChanged` event I added `DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = valorqnt` so I could revert the value.

Code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
   'this part is to check the total of the product in the db
    Dim Produtoid As String = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
    Dim tabelaqndDisponivel As DataTable = CAD.GetData("SELECT quantidadeExistenteProduto FROM Produto where idProduto = " & Produtoid)
    'qntDisponivel is a integer that holds the total quantity of the product in the db
    Dim qntDisponivel As Integer = tabelaqndDisponivel.Rows(0).Item(0)

    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value <= qntDisponivel Then
        'inserts normally
    Else
        'now here the value on cell "quantidade" reverts to the value before being changed  
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = valorqnt
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you've sorted it. The use of `Tag` may be an option as shown by the other answer. I've provided an answer on trying to minimise potential runtime errors. Worth a look over.